# Entity Framework updating [Timestamp] property on parent entity unexpectedly

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 (for .NET 4) and making use of the **TimestampAttribute** for optimistic concurrency checking. However I'm seeing strange/unexpected behavior where the version/timestamp of parent entities are updated as a result only of their children being updated.

This is best explained through example code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /*[ConcurrencyCheck]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [Column(TypeName = "rowversion")]*/
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent : Entity
    {
        public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : Entity
    {
        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
        // Uncommenting property below causes the parent version to be unexpectedly updated when its child is updated.
        // This occurs regardless of whether the Version property is decorated with [Timestamp] or [ConcurrencyCheck].
        //public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestDbContext>());
            var child = new Child {Name = "Child"};
            var parent = new Parent {Name = "Parent", Children = new List<Child> {child}};
            using (var context = new TestDbContext())
            {
                context.Parents.Add(parent);
                context.SaveChanges();
                var originalParentVersion = parent.Version.ToArray();
                child.Name = "New Child Name";
                context.SaveChanges();
                if (!originalParentVersion.SequenceEqual(parent.Version))
                    throw new Exception("Not expected");
            }
            Console.Write("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this simple console application as is, the 'Not expected' exception is not thrown. However, if I uncomment the ID foreign key property (ParentID) then the exception will be thrown.

Can anyone explain this strange behavior? Is this a bug?

Comment: FYI, this question was linked to on the EF Forum and there has been some discussion on it there: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a1059c15-bfaf-42e9-9bee-509273278300/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description seems to match an issue in EF4 for which we released a hotfix:

[FIX: The principal entity in an SQL application generates unnecessary updates when the application uses the Entity Framework in the .NET Framework 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624)

There is no direct download link for the hotfix so you will have to follow some instructions to obtain it. Otherwise the fix is also included in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the hotfix. I haven't been able to test it given it is not easily available for download. However, based on the description, I'm assuming it addresses the unexpected behavior I'm seeing.

It looks like this has been addressed in .NET 4.5 and we're planning to upgrade so I think we'll set this aside as a known issue until then.